WIN 10 Kiosk PC using PowerPoint Viewer Not Working
So I am trying to use Kiosk Mode on a PC to display digital signage. We don't want to assign a license to the PC, so we are trying to use PowerPoint Viewer.
I get the PC to launch into the Kiosk account automatically, but I am getting an error 0x0004005 error code.
I used this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/assigned-access/quickstart-kiosk?tabs=ps
And here is the code:
$assignedAccessConfiguration = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AssignedAccessConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/2017/config" xmlns:rs5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/201810/config" xmlns:v4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/2021/config">
  <Profiles>
    <Profile Id="{EDB3036B-780D-487D-A375-69369D8A8F78}">
      <KioskModeApp v4:ClassicAppPath="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\PPTVIEW.EXE />
      <v4:BreakoutSequence Key="Ctrl+Alt+Del" />
    </Profile>
  </Profiles>
  <Configs>
    <Config>
      <AutoLogonAccount rs5:DisplayName="PPT Display Kiosk" />
      <DefaultProfile Id="{EDB3036B-780D-487D-A375-69369D8A8F78}" />
    </Config>
  </Configs>
</AssignedAccessConfiguration>
"@

$namespaceName="root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"
$className="MDM_AssignedAccess"
$obj = Get-CimInstance -Namespace $namespaceName -ClassName $className
$obj.Configuration = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode($assignedAccessConfiguration)
Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj


Didn't you mean error code 0x80004005 ? That should be a permission error. Try to run the code as user SYSTEM.
